# Python can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to evaluate a formula, `np` is `numpy`:

```
Ds = pow(10,5)
D = np.linspace(0, pow(10,6), 100)
alpha=1.44
beta=0.44
A=alpha*(D/Ds)
L=1.65
buf2=L/4.343
buf=pow(-(alpha*[D/Ds]),beta)
value=exp(buf)
```

and then I will plot this data but I get:

```
buf=pow(-(alpha*[D/Ds]),beta)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: It's worth noting that you've already computing `A=alpha*(D/Ds)` properly up above, so… why not just use `buf=pow(-A, beta)`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Change:

```
buf=pow(-(alpha*[D/Ds]),beta)
```

to:

```
buf=pow(-(alpha*(D/Ds)),beta)
```

This:

```
[D/Ds]
```

gives you list with one element.

But this:

```
alpha * (D/Ds)
```

computes the divisions before the multiplication with `alpha`.

You can multiply a list by an integer:

```
>>> [1] * 4
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

but not by a float:

```
[1] * 4.0
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

since you cannot have partial elements in a list.

Parenthesis can be used for grouping in the mathematical calculations:

```
>>> (1 + 2) * 4
12
```

Comment: And to make it explicit: change the square brackets around `D/Ds` (which define a list) into parenthesis.

Comment: thanks. Interestingly now I got 'nan' as returned. Any ideas ?

Comment: @y33t That would probably be a matter for a separate question.

Comment: @y33t: Given that `alpha` and `Ds` are positive, and all of the `D` values are positive, you're raising a bunch of negative numbers to a fractional power. The solution depends on the problem: did you want complex numbers, or did you get your algorithm wrong?

Comment: @abarnert yes I mistyped ; buf=exp(-(alpha*(D/Ds)),beta) but now I get TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'

Comment: @y33t: First, if you have a new question, open a new question; answering followups via comments is next to impossible. Second, if you're getting confused by a complicated expression, break it up into simple pieces by storing each intermediate result in a variable: `DDs = D/Ds`, then `aDDs = alpha*DDs`, etc. Then, the problem and its solution will likely be obvious to you—and, if it isn't, it will almost certainly be obvious to someone on SO.

Comment: @y33t: Again, you already _did_ half of that, correctly, with `A=alpha*(D/Ds)`. So, why not actually _use_ `A` in your expression, instead of using `alpha*(D/Ds)` again?