# Implementing a custom loss function in Keras with a term like l1 regularisation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I am creating my own loss function (that I want to use in eager execution in Keras).
I would like to add to it a term similar to a l1 loss function.

That is the loss function I am using now

```
def loss(model, x, y, x_dev, y_dev, variables):
  y_ = model(x)
  y_dev_ = model(x_dev)

  y_temp = 1.5

  return loss_mae(y_true=y, y_pred=y_)+y_temp*
                K.mean(tf.convert_to_tensor(variables))
```

with

```
import keras.backend as K
def loss_mae(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred-y_true))
```

my idea is to add to my loss function a constant (`y_temp`) and then I would like to multiply it for the trainable variables (to achieve something similar to a l1 regularisation term).

I tried passing to the `loss()` function `model.trainable_variables` but that does not work and I get a

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float32'
```

anyone has any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because in Python your expression
    `y_temp*variables`
means something like "take `variables` `y_temp` times and merge them in one `sequence`".

In other words, `2 * [1, 2, 3]` is not `[4, 5, 6]`, but `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. Obviously, it makes little sense to use anything but integer in this case.

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to perform element-wise multiplication. To achieve this you should use list comprehension, something like `[x * 1.5 for x in [1, 2, 3]]`

By the way, you could also check these answers to similar questions:
[Python can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994648/python-cant-multiply-sequence-by-non-int-of-type-float) and [How do I multiply each element in a list by a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166633/how-do-i-multiply-each-element-in-a-list-by-a-number/35166661)

Comment: Thanks... I just noticed that and was about to correct it... Dumb error. But I still have the same problem... I will probably solve it by using low-level API in Tensorflow. Thanks anyway...

Comment: Not quite. I modified my question further to add more information of what I tried. It possibly too complicated to explain here... But I will try. Will updated it before lunch.